# How to log in C# Azure function class static methods

Tags: c#, logging, azure-functions

I am trying to make a one time connection to the BlobServiceClient i.e. when the Function App is started then use that BlobServiceClient everytime the Http call is made. For that, I've created a method

```
GetBlobSerViceClient()
```

That'll create a blobserviceclient using the endpoint of the blob service and the ManagedIdentity.
I'll need to log the message if anything fails in this method and was wondering what would be the best approach to do that?

Here is the code sample:

```
    public static BlobServiceClient storageBlobClient = GetBlobServiceClient();
    private static BlobServiceClient GetBlobServiceClient()
    {
        if(storageEndpoint == null)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Storage endpoint is null.");
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", nameof(storageEndpoint));
        }
        try
        {
            return new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(storageEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential(includeInteractiveCredentials: true));
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

           //TODO  log message here
           
            throw  ex;
        }
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        \\body
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'll need to log the message if anything fails in this method.

One of the workarounds is to use Azure SQL to save all the messages that are being logged.

Steps to store your data:

1. Create a SQL Database resource.
2. Connect to the Azure SQL Database.
3. Create a simple table that can be used to store the log messages.
4. Copy the connection string of your SQL Database and add in the following code.

```
// Adding custom code to log messages to the Azure SQL Database

// Creating the connection string
string connectionString = "<YOUR CONNECTION STRING>";

// Using the connection string to open a connection
try {
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

    // Opening a connection
    connection.Open();

    // Defining the log message and Create Date
    var logMessage = $ "{name} has logged in.";
    var createDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Prepare the SQL Query
    var query = $ "INSERT INTO [ApplicationLogs] ([LogMessage],[CreateDate]) VALUES('{logMessage}', '{createDate}')";

    // Prepare the SQL command and execute query
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    // Open the connection, execute and close connection
    if (command.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) {

      command.Connection.Close();
    }
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Logging messages from Azure Functions to Azure SQL Database](https://www.sqlshack.com/logging-messages-from-azure-functions-to-azure-sql-database/)